# How to install slurm-seff in Ubuntu

Tags: apt, software-installation, dpkg, perl

I am trying to install [Slurm-seff](https://bugs.schedmd.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1611) Perl package into Ubuntu 19.10.

It has `.rpm` package to install https://pkgs.org/download/slurm-seff ; but I am unable to install `alien` to install the `.rpm` package.

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 alien : Depends: debhelper (>= 7) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Also for `libslurm-perl` and `libslurmdb-perl` packages:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libslurm-perl libslurmdb-perl
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libslurm-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.18.2
 libslurmdb-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.18.2
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

---

Since it is a `perl` script I try to run it but unable to make it work from the following approach:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/SchedMD/slurm.git
$ cd slurm/contribs/seff
$ perl seff
Use of uninitialized value $FindBin::Bin in concatenation (.) or string at seff line 11.
Can't locate Slurmdb.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Slurmdb module) (@INC contains: /../lib/perl /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.28.1 /usr/local/share/perl/5.28.1 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.28 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.28 /usr/share/perl/5.28 /usr/local/lib/site_perl /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base) at seff line 12.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at seff line 12.
```

Related to this I wasn't able to find any guide.

---

I am recommended to ask [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64508367/2402577) in [askubuntu.com](http://askubuntu.com)  rather than SO.

---

**Update**:

```
$ sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libjs-modernizr python3-sip
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.

$ dpkg --get-selections | grep hold # returns empty string

$ sudo apt-get update
Ign:1 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/4.2 InRelease
Ign:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty InRelease
Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/dawidd0811/neofetch/ubuntu eoan InRelease
Hit:4 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/4.2 Release
Hit:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security InRelease
Hit:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates InRelease
Hit:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-backports InRelease
Ign:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan InRelease
Hit:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty Release
Err:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
Hit:11 http://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

$ sudo apt-get autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

Comment: The seff command is a Perl script. There is no need to compile/build it. Just copy it to a location present in your PATH env variable and you should be able to use it. And install libslurmdb-perl and libslurm-perl to run it.

Comment: I am having following error when I try to install the app: `libslurm-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.18.2
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.` also script does not work without building it , I am just unable to make it work

Comment: What  Ubuntu are you using? Your problem is mostly installing Alien.  I did install the package correctly on my Ubuntu 20.04.1.

Comment: @PhilippeDelteil  its `Ubuntu 19.10`

Comment: @alper please paste the output of `sudo apt-get install -f` AND dpkg --get-selections | grep hold   AND sudo apt-get update.

sudo apt-get autoremove

Comment: @PhilippeDelteil I have updated the question, please let me know if you require any more information

Comment: @alper Your sources.list is messed up. There is no point of using 14.04 Trusty Tahr and 16.04 Xenial Xerus repository if you're using 19.10 Eoan Ermine. Also, it's been more than 4 months since 19.10 reached end of life. Eoan's repository information and packages are now hosted at old-releases.ubuntu.com. You must restore default repositories for Eoan Ermine and then change the URL to old-releases. To get started see [How do I restore the default repositories?](/q/124017) and [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](/q/91815).

Comment: I agree with Kulfy, first you need to fix the repositories. I'd upgrade to 20.04.1 .

Comment: I have upgraded to `Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS` but I am still seeing the same error starting with `Can't locate Slurmdb.pm in @INC` on my question